# Julia how to create an array of type(structure as C)?

Tags: types, julia

How can I create a array with the type of parameters as below

```
   type :: test
   x :: Int32
   y :: Float32 
   end
```

Comment: `test[]`. Also, syntax is `type test` -- please see the manual.

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to read a binary file with a array of structure (type as in Julia?) . For now, I can read the parameters of structure one by one using the syntax read. How can I define the type of array and read the total file together?

Comment: If you want to ask a separate question then please create another one. Also you should check out (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). But it seems as if a bit of background reading of the julia docs would go a long way indeed http://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/

Answer (score 1):

```
julia> struct Test
         x::Int32
         y::Float32
       end

julia> f = open("rand.bin","r")

julia> read(f, Test, 1)
1-element Array{Test,1}:
 Test(55238752, 1.67109)
```

(for Julia 0.5, use `immutable` rather than `struct`)